# How can i convert this function to prepared statment?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this ajax request and it inserts data into the database without any problems but when I tried to wrap it to a prepared statement doesn't work!

```
$number = count($_POST["title"]);
if($number > 0)
{
    for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)
    {
        if(trim($_POST["title"][$i] != ''))
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO navigations (secret_api_key, title, link) VALUES ('".$_SESSION["secret_api_key"]."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["title"][$i])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["url"][$i])."')";
            mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        }
    }
    echo "Data Inserted";
} else {
    echo "Enter Name";
}
```

This is the prepared statement i tried:

```
$number = count($_POST["title"]);
if($number > 0)
{
    for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)
    {
        if(trim($_POST["title"][$i] != ''))
        {
            $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO navigations (secret_api_key, title, link) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
            $sql->bind_param("sss", '.$_SESSION["secret_api_key"].", ".$_POST["title"][$i].", ".$_POST["url"][$i]."');
            $sql->execute();
        }
    }
    echo "Data Inserted";
} else {
    echo "Enter Name";
}
```

maybe it will be solved if ".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["url"][$i])." converted

Comment: Can you show the prepared statement version too?

Comment: How did you try to convert this function into a prepared statement and what error did you get?

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @tadman i updated my code now

Comment: @Shadow i updated my code now but it doesn't give me any errors!

Comment: Those single quotes are messing things up. `"sss"` implies three string values, but those single quotes make it only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're certainly getting closer but you must pay very close attention to PHP syntax. This is programming, *every character matters*.

Here's a reworked version:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO navigations (secret_api_key, title, link) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$sql->bind_param('sss', $_SESSION["secret_api_key"], $_POST["title"][$i], $_POST["url"][$i]);
$sql->execute();
```

Note that you send in bare arguments, not strings, or parts of strings or strings with left-over bits of concatenation in there. Just regular variables doing regular variable things.

If you're not using a syntax-highlighting editor, or you don't have that feature turned on, it can be a great help in identifying problems like this. You can see in your snippet that the syntax *looks* wrong just based on color. Most developers find this invaluable at preventing simple, but easily made mistakes.

Comment: actually the first attempt I made it like this but with a wrong session but didn't work and now also but after I checked my URL it was serialized with old data and after reloading it works now, thanks tadman you saved my day :)